# Postgresql Centos Issue

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to enable Postgresql 9.3 to accept remote connections on CentOS6. I opened the port in iptables, set the port to 5432 in the pgconf file, set listen_addresses to '*' (accept all connections), and allow addresses in the pg_hba with host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust. The postmaster is running on 5432. However, I still receive the following error. How do I get a valid connection?

The error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "50.63.141.236" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Relevant part of pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
#opens postgres to the internet
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             trust
```

Relevant output from iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:postgres
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:postgres

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:postgres
```

Finally, proof that postmaster is running.

```
EN      1433/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432              0.0.0.0:*                   LIST
```

Comment: Why 0.0.0.0/0 trust and not md5?

Comment: Are you sure 0.0.0.0 is what you want -- as I understand it, this is an IP header for unknown. In our pg_hba.conf file, (also pg9.3 and centos), we have our actual external IP address, followed by 32, eg, 123.123.123.123/32

Comment: `0.0.0.0/0` matches all IP addresses, because the subnet mask prefix `/0` doesn't mask anything. So that's OK, so long as you're not Internet-facing.

Comment: I'm just trying to get it to work at the moment so I am not worried about IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't restarted PostgreSQL after changing `listen_addresses`. It's still listening on `127.0.0.1`, i.e. loopback only. Or you edited the config file for a different PostgreSQL install.

If you connect to host `127.0.0.1` port `5432` it'll work. Or make sure you edited the right config and restart (not just reload) PostgreSQL.

Comment: I restarted 3-4 times. Also, I can connect at 127.0.0.1 but not externally so it seems my problem is with some firewall I don't know about or something similar. I edited the iptables though so it doesn't appear to be that. I even rebooted the entire system when restarting the services failed.

Comment: `SHOW config_file;` - make sure you edited the right one. Also `SHOW listen_addresses`. It isn't firewall related - your question clearly shows that Pg is listening only on the loopback interface, look at your netstat output.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I had updated postgres tp 9.1 but forgot. I just went ahead and reprovisioned the server since it was being converted to a db server without data at the moment.